# How do I make this query correct for selecting the required item?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi I am having this problem with my database, my database is called `DatabaseClass`. The database basically stores my information for bank's name, account number of customer and the balance.I have two spinners in one of my activities which shows me the bank and the account number for the particular bank selected.  On selecting one of the banks, the corresponding account numbers for that bank in the other spinner are displayed, till this its working fine, now when an 'account number' is selected I am trying to retrieve the balance in that account

Here's the code I am using:

```
account_for_spiiner_account=cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.KEY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_ID));

c= myDatabase.getAmountfor_Account(account_for_spiiner_account);
```

And here's the code for getting the amount for that particular account number:

```
public Cursor getAmountfor_Account(String account_for_spiiner_account) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_ACCOUNT, new String[] {
            DatabaseClass.KEY_ROW_ID, DatabaseClass.KEY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_ID,
            DatabaseClass.KEY_AMOUNT_ID }, KEY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { account_for_spiiner_account }, null,null,null);
}
```

I am trying to collect the amount as a `String` in a variable and to check the amount got I made a `Toast`. But the toast is showing nothing as such, any idea where I am getting wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you made any other query that does return a result? It could be good that you make sure that it's not caused by any KEY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_ID; narrow down and ask again :)

Comment: Yes I did, I got the bank's name from the spinner1 and put passed that bank's name to the Database class's getAccontData( String bankName) function. I got the account numbers for the bank selected. Here's the code for the 'getAccountData(String )' function:->                  public       Cursor getAccountData(String bank) {

 return myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_ACCOUNT, new String[]      {
    DatabaseClass.KEY_ROW_ID,      DatabaseClass.KEY_BANK_NAME_ID,
    DatabaseClass.KEY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_ID      }, KEY_BANK_NAME_ID + "=?",
    new String[] { bank }, null, null,      null);

 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was using the wrong balance entry to retrieve, solved my own problem.